# ClassNotFoundException even after adding dependecy jars

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I'm creating a simple REST web service using Jersey. And when I try to run it on the server(Tomcat 7) I'm getting the following exception. I can see in my Maven dependecy library that the class(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer) is already present.Need help.

```
Exception: 
SEVERE: Servlet /SampleJersey threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

1.I have added the extra maven dependency core and servlet and tried. But it did not work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2. I tried the following as well:
   Right click on project --> Build Path --> Build Path --> Add Library --> Server Runtime --> Apache Tomcat v7.0

Here's my pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And web.xml:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
 </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are running the project as dynamic web project on a server within eclipse, so you should open the project properties and send the maven dependencies to the server directory by adding the maven dependency to deployment assembly.

1. Right click on Project -> properties -> deployment assembly -> add -> java build path entries -> maven dependency